# Tag request: bbdb-3

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation

Could someone please tag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148907/ignore-addresses-from-mailing-list-mail-with-bbdb-in-emacs) with [bbdb-3](/questions/tagged/bbdb-3)?

[*bbdbv3*](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/bbdb/) is significantly different from earlier incarnations, as it is a complete rewrite, so I think it deserves its own tag.

Comment: Leaving a comment on your question should be more than enough to request a tag to be created for you. You don't need to bring it here.  p.s., I created the tags for you on both your questions as `[bbdb-3]` to fit our pattern of `name-version`.

Comment: @JeffMercado Please repost your comment as an answer, especially since you actually fulfilled the request.

Comment: @Anna: Ok fine. :)

Comment: Geez, this thing doesn't have any better name than bbdb?

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tagged your questions as [bbdb-3](/questions/tagged/bbdb-3) to conform to our naming conventions.

Just leave a comment on your question next time and I'm sure someone with the reputation would be more than happy to add it for you.